# Stuck on Serialization in C#

Tags: c#, serialization, binaryformatter

I have a class that handles serialization in C#, called Serializer.  It's implementation is below:

```
public class Serializer
{
    public void SerializeRulesManager(string filename, RulesManager rulesManager)
    {
        Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Create);        
        try
        {
            BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            binaryFormatter.Serialize(stream, rulesManager);             
        }
        finally
        {
            stream.Close();
        }                
    }

    public RulesManager DeserializeRulesManager(string filename)
    {
        RulesManager rulesManager = null;
        Stream stream = File.Open(filename, FileMode.Open);
        try
        {
            BinaryFormatter binaryFormatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            rulesManager = (RulesManager)binaryFormatter.Deserialize(stream);                
        }
        finally
        {
            stream.Close();                
        }                       
        return rulesManager;
    }
}
```

Pretty straightforward stuff, and it works just fine with all of my unit tests.  The RulesManager is correctly serialized and deserialized so I know the graph is good.

The trouble comes with the following code:

```
public void Save(string filename)
{
    Cursor.Current = Cursors.WaitCursor;
    try
    {
        _serializer.SerializeRulesManager(filename, _rulesManager);
    }
    catch (System.Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }            
    finally
    {
        Cursor.Current = Cursors.Default;
    }
}
```

That function is part of the Manager class.  The Manager class is instantiated on the MainForm.  The MainForm uses a SaveFileDialog to prompt the user for the filename and location they want to save to and then makes the following call:

```
saveFileDialog.InitialDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
if (saveFileDialog.ShowDialog(this) == DialogResult.OK)
{
    _manager.Save(saveFileDialog.FileName);
}
```

Thus calling the function above.  When it does so, I get the following exception in Serialize.SerializeRulesManager at the binaryFormatter.Serialize(stream, rulesManager) line:

> Type 'TestHarness.MainForm' in Assembly 'TestHarness, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null' is not marked as serializable.

Why would MainForm need to be marked as Serializable?  Just for kicks, I put the Serializable attribute on MainForm and it just moved the exception up one level to say that Windows.Form was not marked as Serializable.  What gives?

Comment: can you share the implementation of RulesManager

Comment: One more reason not to pass around references to your form classes :)

Comment: Just a small note: replace your try/finally blocks with `using() {}` blocks where possible. Easier and more reliable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RulesManager  probably has a reference to MainForm.  If so, mark it as not serialized with the 
[NonSerializedAttrbibute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute.aspx)

Comment: Well that's what I get for posting at the end of a work-day instead of sleeping on it.  I completely overlooked the event exposed by RulesManager that MainForm was hooked to.  The even wasn't marked as [field:NonSerializable] and I wasn't unhooking the event in the MainForm and so it was trying to serialize the MainForm as well.

Marking the event as [field:NonSerializable] fixed the problem.